# Modify values within the MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

I have a `DataFrame A`

```
     DataFrame A
| I1  | I2 |  Rank  |
| -------- |--------|

| 1   | a  |   1    |
| 1   | b  |   2    |

| 2   | a  |   1    |
| 2   | b  |   2    |
| 2   | c  |   3    |
```

and I have a maximum value of rank for each `I1` found by `z.groupby('I1').max()`

```
    max A
| I1  |  Rank  |
| --- |--------|

| 1   |   2    |
| 2   |   3    |
```

now I want to change my dataframe base on that 2 input and make the rest `NaN`

```
     Desire Output
| I1  | I2 |  Rank  |
| -------- |--------|

| 1   | a  |  NaN   |
| 1   | b  |  num1  |

| 2   | a  |  NaN   |
| 2   | b  |  NaN   |
| 2   | c  |  num2  |
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Why you have a [multi-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-index) tag in your question/title ? Can you make an example with the `pd.DataFrame` constructor ? [pandas-minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use :

```
m = df.groupby("I1")["Rank"].transform("max").ne(df["Rank"])

df["Rank"] = df["Rank"].mask(m, other=np.nan) # `np.nan` by default
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   I1 I2  Rank
0   1  a   NaN
1   1  b  2.00
2   2  a   NaN
3   2  b   NaN
4   2  c  3.00
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'I1': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
     'I2': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
     'Rank': [np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan, 3.0]}
)
```

Comment: What if the condition is something like >= 2?

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: Keep the rank that is >= 2 instead of max rank for each I1 and change it to some arbitrary number

Comment: That's not what you're asking for in your question. You should update the given example and make sure to update the expected output as well. Or, to avoid moving targets, you should [open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new *question*.